# clojure gen-class returning own class

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm now making a class object with Clojure which has a method returning the object itself.

Written with Java, the object that I'd like to make is like,

```
class Point {
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point copy() {
        return new Point(this.x, this.y);
    }
}
```

The current clojure code that I wrote is like,

```
(ns myclass.Point
  :gen-class
  :prefix "point-"
  :init init
  :state state
  :constructors {[double double] []}
  :methods [[copy [] myclass.Point]]))

(defn point-init [x y]
   [[] {:x x :y y}])

(defn point-copy [this]
   this)
```

However, I got an error as follows.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myclass.Point
```

While I have googled about this issue, I couldn't find any answers. Does anyone know the solution for this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the only way, but, in order to use the generated class type in a method signature, you can generate the class in 2 steps - though it's still in one file and compiled in one pass:

- call `gen-class` with only the constructors
- call `gen-class` again with state, full set of constructors and methods.

I tried with various methods including forward declaration, but only the above was working eventually. I did extend your example a little bit. Note That the `copy` method is not very useful *as-is* since `Point` is immutable, but you may want to provide mutators to your class.

Full listing:

```
(ns points.Point)

;; generate a simple class with the constructors used in the copy method
(gen-class
 :name points.Point
 :init init
 :constructors {[] []
                [double double] []})

;; generate the full class 
(gen-class
 :name points.Point
 :prefix pt-
 :main true
 :state coordinates
 :init init
 :constructors {[] []
                [double double] []}
 :methods [[distance [points.Point] double]
           [copy [] points.Point]])

(defn pt-init
  ([] (pt-init 0 0))
  ([x y]
   [[] {:x x :y y}]))

(defn pt-copy 
  "Return a copy of this point"
  [this]
  (points.Point. (:x (.coordinates this)) (:y (.coordinates this))))

(defn pt-distance [^points.Point this ^points.Point p]
  (let [dx (- (:x (.coordinates this)) (:x (.coordinates p)))
        dy (- (:y (.coordinates this)) (:y (.coordinates p)))]
    (Math/sqrt (+ (* dx dx) (* dy dy)))))

(defn pt-toString [this]
  (str "Point: " (.coordinates this)))

;; Testing Java constructors and method call on Point class
(import (points Point))
(defn pt-main []
  (let [o (Point.)
        p (points.Point. 3 4)]
    (println (.toString o))
    (println (.toString p))
    (println (.distance o p))
    (println (.distance p (.copy p)))))
```

---

In order to generate the classes, configure `project.clj` with the line

```
:aot [points.Point]
```

Testing with `lein` gives:

```
tgo$ lein clean
tgo$ lein compile
Compiling points.Point
tgo$ lein run
Point: {:x 0, :y 0}
Point: {:x 3.0, :y 4.0}
5.0
0.0
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding but thank you very much for your kind answer. The code was quite helpful for me to revise my code!

Answer (score 0):

## Cause analysis

The issue is because the compiler doesn't know about `myclass.Point` in the `:methods` directive before the class `myclass.Point` is actually generated. Although this isn't an issue to a Java class but Clojure compiler doesn't seem to support this use case, (perhaps for good reasons.)

## Solution

I feel it's much easier to implement interfaces (in the `:implements` directive) other than defining custom methods like your example. This might also suggest the good practice of "programming to interfaces." Generating interface from Clojure is doable, e.g. [`gen-interface`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/gen-interface). Just make sure the `gen-interface` is compiled aot, before the `gen-class` form.

Alternatively, I prefer to create a polyglot project with interfaces in Java and implementations in Clojure. Here's the code snippet to do so with leiningen:

```java
// src/java/points/Point.java
package points;

public interface Point {
    public double distant(Point p);
    public Point copy();
}
```

```clj
;; project.clj
(defproject
  ;; Change these. The rests are the same.
  :aot [points.java-class]
  :source-paths ["src/clojure"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"])

;; src/clojure/points/java_class.clj
(ns points.java-class
  (:gen-class
   :name points.Point2D
   :implements [points.Point]  ;; no more ClassNotFoundException
   :prefix "point-"
   :init init
   :state state
   :constructors {[double double] []})

;; rests are the same
```

This works because Leiningen compiles the java sources first by default.

This answer is also covered in my [article](https://dawranliou.com/interop-legacy-java-with-clojure.html#interop-legacy-java-with-clojure), although I modified the
code snippet to fit your question.